# CSS Font Issue in Mobile Mode

Tags: css, flexbox

There's an issue with the font size & flex box when it's being displayed in the mobile mode..
In Monitor view, the font size is 14px but when i change it to Mobile it turned into 33.4px.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJsFN.png)

Comment: No code shared = we can't help.

Comment: Please show your css and html code.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you did not specify a fixed value for the tag with text

```css
p{font-size:14px;}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```